# Turtles: shifting on the y axis using a for loop

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So I'm trying to create a tessellation using turtle graphics, and I have code that I think should be working, but it clearly isn't. It should be taking user input to determine the size of the hex, then using that same input for spacing by doubling the input and moving to the next hex. It works as far as one line of hexagons go. But when I try to use that same method by adding the size * 2 to the y coordinate (see: for a in range(20): loop)) it just runs the same line of hexes 20 times. How can I get the y coordinate to use the size to place the next line of hexes below the first one, and so on?

And this is for school, but I've been at this for 6 hours now and I still have 4 hour's of calc, so I'm a little desperate.

Thanks!

```
#learned nifty * trick
from turtle import *

x = -500
y = 300
size = float(input("How large would you like the hexagons to be? 1-50" ))

#Should only need one turtle
#Need shapes - Picked hexagon

bgcolor("gray")
speed(10)
begin_fill()
color("red")

for a in range(20):
    penup()
    goto(x,y -(size * 2))
    pendown()
    for b in range(20):
        penup()
        forward(size*2)
        pendown()
            for c in range(6):
                forward(size)
                left(60)


end_fill()



#Need 3 elements
    #size of octogon
    #direction of octogon
    #coordinates of octogons
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although some of your constants make perfect sense:

```
forward(size*2)
for c in range(6):
left(60)
```

Others are quite arbitrary:

```
x = -500
y = 300
for a in range(20):
for b in range(20):
```

And should be calculated if possible.  You really can't work with hexagons without using the square root of 3.  Although `size * 2` is the *width* of your hexagons, their *height* is really `size * 3 ** 0.5` not `size * 2`.  Let's rewrite your code to avoid arbitrary numbers and actually calculate as best we can:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle  # unlearn nifty * trick

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1000, 600

ROOT = 3 ** 0.5

size = float(input("How large would you like the hexagons to be? (5-50): "))

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.bgcolor('gray')

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.fillcolor('red')
turtle.penup()

left_edge = size/2 - WIDTH/2
x, y = left_edge, HEIGHT/2 - size * ROOT

screen.tracer(False)  # because I have no patience

for row in range(int(HEIGHT // (size * ROOT)) + 1):
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.begin_fill()

    for column in range(int(WIDTH // (size * 2)) + 1):
        turtle.pendown()

        for _ in range(6):
            turtle.forward(size)
            turtle.left(60)

        turtle.penup()
        turtle.forward(size * 2)

    turtle.end_fill()

    x = left_edge
    y -= size * ROOT

screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

That is all well and good, but if our goal is a *tessellation* then we may want to adjust things a bit to actually tile the plane.  The above code will need five lines modified:

```
5c5
< ROOT = 3 ** 0.5
---
> ROOT = 3 ** 0.5 / 2
22c22
< for row in range(int(HEIGHT // (size * ROOT)) + 1):
---
> for row in range(int(HEIGHT // (size * ROOT)) + 2):
26c26
<   for column in range(int(WIDTH // (size * 2)) + 1):
---
>   for column in range(int(WIDTH // (size * 1.5)) + 1):
34c34
<       turtle.forward(size * 2)
---
>       turtle.forward(size * 3)
38c38
<   x = left_edge
---
>   x = left_edge - (row + 1) % 2 * size * 1.5
```

Only the last of these is a modification beyond changing a small constant.  In order to make the tiles nestle, we need to introduce a concept of *parity* so each row alternates as to where the hexagon begins:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you do not update `y` at each iteration.

Replace the line:

```
goto(x,y -(size * 2))
```

with:

```
y = y - (size * 2)
goto(x,y)
```

and the following lines of hexagons are drawn below the previous ones.